# Bottom navigation setOnItemSelectedListener return super

Tags: android, kotlin

I have botton navation setup up as below and it works all right.

```
navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.nav_1, R.id.nav_2))
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
binding.bottomNavView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Now I would like to prevent switching fragments if current fragment is the second one and it has some flag set in it.

I've tried using `bottomNavView.setOnItemSelectedListener` but it breaks the entire nav controller mechanism and requires doing fragment and title swithcing by yourself.

Is there any other way of overriding nav controller behaviour for a pariticular item and let it handle the rest as usual with something like `super.onItemSelected()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [the `setupWithNavController()` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#setupWithNavController(com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView,androidx.navigation.NavController)):

> This will call [`onNavDestinationSelected`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,androidx.navigation.NavController)) when a menu item is selected.

So you can simply call that method if you want to do the default behavior from your own listener.

```
// Call setupWithNavController to get the automatic
// selection of the correct bottom nav item
// based on the NavController's state
binding.bottomNavView.setupWithNavController(navController)
// Then override the OnItemSelectedListener
// with your own with your custom logic
binding.bottomNavView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
    if (navController.currentDestination?.id == R.id.fragment_id && !yourConditionIsMet) {
        // Return false to not allow navigating to the tab
        false
    } else {
        // Do the default behavior
        onNavDestinationSelected(
            item,
            navController
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. Thanks! The function name `onNavDestinationSelected` is missleading.

Comment: What then is the right function name? @yaugenka

Answer (score 0):

You can use **addOnDestinationChangedListener()** into the **navController** then compare the current destination with fragment id

```
 navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, _, _ ->

        if (navController.currentDestination?.id == R.id.fragment_id) {
            
        }
        else {
             
        }
    }
```

Comment: The method is called `after` navigation is complete. So cannot prevent a navigatoin with it.